# ionic2: has no exported member 'ionicBootstrap'

Tags: ionic-framework

I keep finding with issue when trying to use the ionicBootstrap. I'm pretty sure everything is quite updated, and I also tried starting a blank project, and just doing:

```
import { Platform, ionicBootstrap } from 'ionic-angular';
```

Gives me this error already :(

Any ideas? :/

ionic info:

```
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.4
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.2
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.38
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Mac OS X Sierra
Node Version: v7.0.0
```

Thank you!

Comment: Look this:
[link](https://stackoverflow.unlockproject.space/q/38327659)

Comment: link not working.. having same problem with ionic2 rc3 , any new about that