# cloud-angular has no exported member provideCloud

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

**THE SITUATION**

I have setup a blank app. Installed `@ionic/cloud-angular` and imported `provideCloud`.

But I am getting the following error:

```
cloud-angular has no exported member 'provideCloud'
```

[image: cloud-angular has no exported member provideCloud]

(I have a similar error for ionicBootstrap)

**THE STEPS:**

1. ionic start whateva blank --v2
2. npm install @ionic/cloud-angular --save
3. ionic io init
4. Import provideCloud

**THE CODE:**

```
import { provideCloud, CloudSettings } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';
import { ionicBootstrap, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
```

**Ionic info**:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.2
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.44
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0
ios-sim version: 5.0.11
OS: OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.6.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.3.1 Build version 7D1014
```

**Package.json dependencies:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.1",
    "@ionic/cloud-angular": "^0.7.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.44",
    "typescript": "2.0.6"
  },
```

**THE QUESTION:**

Why I am getting the error?

I have just setup a new blank app.. There is something wrong in the setup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When version **0.7.0** was released, `provideCloud` was replaced with `CloudModule` as you can see in their [code](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cloud-angular/commit/e3d0891fe596e834ecff59c96bf3417038cb9763).

The new way to set up your cloud setting is as follows

```
import { CloudSettings, CloudModule } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';

const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
  'core': {
    'app_id': 'APP_ID'
  }
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [ ... ],
  providers: [ ... ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thank you! cloudSettings should be initialize only in app.module.ts or also in app.component.ts?

Comment: Btw.. do you have an answer to a similar problem regarding ionicBootstrap? There is already here a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328716/ionic2-has-no-exported-member-ionicbootstrap

Comment: Only in `app.module.ts`. I believe that you have to import `IonicApp` and `IonicModule` like this `import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';` instead of `ionicBoostrap`, more info here [starter repo](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-tutorial/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts)